# Sum of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}-7\cdot2^{1-n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}-7\cdot2^{1-n}=-7\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2^{1-n}=-7\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}$$

But $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}=2$$
And not $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{1-q}$$ for $|q|<1$

Comment: Check your sums and what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lost an exponent

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}-7\cdot2^{1-n}=-7\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}2^{1-n}=-7\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\color{red}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}$$

and we have that by geometric series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=\frac1{1-\frac12}=2$$

Comment: The sum does not converge!

Comment: sorry I lost the exponent

Comment: @gammatester Thanks to have pointed that out! :)

Comment: @gimusi so $ -7*\frac{1}{2}*2$?

Comment: @newhere Yes indeed $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right)-1=\frac1{1-\frac12}-1=2-1=1$$